# Groupby: multiple selects of radio button

Tags: bootstrap-4

is it possible to allow a radio selection for each Groupby section with the Bootstrap table?

```
https://bootstrap-table.com/
https://live.bootstrap-table.com/example/column-options/radio.html
https://live.bootstrap-table.com/example/extensions/group-by-v2.html
```

Comment: Tell your problem more briefly.

Comment: what is the correct method to allow this functionality within this plugin?